# Recording a flv from an air window. Is it possible.

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, air, video-processing

Is it possible to record and stream an air window to flv?

I would like to be able to use multiple video inputs and use text and graphics. To create a video mixer, picture in picture, key in graphics, etc. I'm able to do this on the display but would like to be able to record and stream it as well. I would also like to retain HD resolution. Recording the window maybe a dirty method. Is there another way?

Can anyone point me to any classes or search terms?

Answer (score 0):

[Lee Felarca](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/) has created an [FLVEncoder class](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/flv-encoder-with-audio/) for AS3 that is very easy to use. For each frame, you can draw your AIR window or rendered frame to a `BitmapData` using [`BitmapData.draw`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) and then feed this to the encoder. Unfortunately, it uses the very simple screen video codec and produces very large video files, which probably isn't suitable for HD.

For a more robust solution, you could try piping the frames to [FFmpeg](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) using AIR's [`NativeProcess`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) APIs. You'd draw your rendered frame to a BitmapData as above, but feeding it to FFmpeg will give you a great boost in speed and allow you to use any video container, codec, and compression settings you'd desire.

Finally, you could always try something like [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) to simply record the screen. You might also be able to launch Fraps using `NativeProcess`.